# Visual Studio Extension VisualDIffFiles opens in another instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I'm using the VisualDiffFiles static function from my Visual Studio extension.  It opens the diff window in another instance of VS ( the one I'm debugging from ), instead of the one I'm running the extension in.  How can I force it to open in the correct VS instance ?

**Edit**
This is the code, run from a UserControl

```
  // Diff params
  string sourceFile = @"c:\temp\Eula1.txt";
  string targetFile = @"c:\temp\Eula2.txt";
  string sourceFileTag = "1";
  string targetFileTag = "2";
  string sourceFileLabel = "1";
  string targetFileLabel = "2";
  bool isSourceReadOnly = true;
  bool isTargetReadOnly = true;

  // Use the VS diff tools
  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Difference.VisualDiffFiles(sourceFile, targetFile, sourceFileTag, targetFileTag,
                                                                            sourceFileLabel, targetFileLabel, isSourceReadOnly, isTargetReadOnly);
```

Comment: please provide related code (vsx) and steps, which we can reproduce the issue on my side.

Comment: I can't give you the extension, it's an internal tool.  I did add the exact code that I'm using to my question above.

Comment: Based on your code, I create a simple custom command by using your code, it show the windows in the running the extension visual studio instance.https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDgQCqFJeRaoMUgjf2

Comment: And now it does for me as well, I guess it was just a one off....

Comment: I glade to know that you resolve the issue, please post a answer, and mark it as answer, it will be beneficial to other communities who have the similar issue.

Comment: After further testing, it happens sometimes other times not.  I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: Do you try the sample which I provide, Does it can reproduce the issue on your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the diff window on current visual studio instance, please use dte.ExecuteCommand method to achieve it. like this:

```
DTE2 dte = (DTE2)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));

string file1 = @"D:\Test\Test1.txt";
string file2 = @"D:\Test\Test2.txt";

dte.ExecuteCommand("Tools.DiffFiles", $"\"{ file1}\" \"{ file2}\"");
```

Comment: That works good, is there any way to customize the caption of the diff window as well ?